# Dynamic link library in C

Tags: c, linker

I have some questions about dynamic link libraries in C.

Q1.
[image]

My textbooks uses a picture to illustrate how DLL works,
and it seems that some relocation and symbol table information of `libvector.so` and `libc.so` are copied (the arrow is attached to their side), but whenever the assembler encounters a reference to an object whose ultimate location is unknown, it generates a relocation entry that tells the linker how to modify the reference when it merges the object file into an executable. For libc.so, everything is known(it has all definitions), so there shouldn't be any relocation entry for libc.so, isn't it

Q2. My textbook says that:

*"a single copy of the .text section of a shared library in memory can be shared by different running processes",*

Let's say I have a program that uses `printf`. Does the `.text` section of `printf` stay in RAM forever or does it get evicted from RAM when the first program finishes, and get loaded in RAM when a second process uses `printf` again?
If the latter is the case, isn't that very inefficient that the `.text` section of `printf` gets evicted and loaded in RAM many many times since we have multiple processes that could be running in the background?

Comment: Subject to paging rules, the text for `printf()` is only evicted when there is no running program using it.  In the case of `printf()`, that is practically (but not theoretically) equivalent to 'never', but only because almost all programs use `printf()`.  If you used the curses library, say, and no running program was using it (which could happen, especially overnight), then it would be evicted when the space was needed for something else.

Comment: Mandatory read : Drepper's [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper (for Linux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q1:**  The diagram you provided seems correct to me.  It is `main2` that is being constructed; the relocation and symbol table information of `libvector.so` and `libc.so` are being copied in so that the final executable can make use of them.  From the perspective of `main2`, functions, constants, etc. from `libc` and `libvector` are being added, so I agree with your textbook that the relocation and symbol table information of `libvector.so` and `libc.so` are being copied.

**Q2:**  You present only the two extremes: "stay in RAM forever" or "evicted from RAM when the first program finished".  Almost certainly, the sharable portions of libraries will stay in RAM as long as some recently-running process has made use of them.  A typical strategy an OS will use is an LRU algorithm to evict 'unused' things from RAM, but only when it wants to load more into RAM than there is room for.  So, on a lightly used machine, nearly everything might hang around in RAM for quite a long time; but on a very heavily overtaxed machine, the OS will be constantly discarding things from RAM that it will need again very soon.  But even then, some things are used so frequently, they are unlikely to ever meet the LRU threshold, so you might have some certain things in RAM for a long time, even if most things are being evicted.

**Q1 follow-up:**  In answer to your question in your comment: correct: there is nothing in `main2.c` to define functions found in `libc`.  It is *because* of this that the linker needs to copy in the relocation and symbol table information for `printf()` from `libc.so`, so that when `main2` is executed, `libc.so` also gets loaded.

In more detail:

`printf()` might be *called* from `main2.c`, but `printf()` is *declared* in `stdio.h` and *defined* in e.g. `printf.c` [1] and *compiled* into `libc.so`; `main2.c` can be *compiled* because the compiler can see the signature for `printf()` (in `stdio.h`), but to build `main2` (the executable), the code already compiled in `libc.so` needs to be *linked* with `main2.o` (the intermediate object file).  `ld` does this by copying in the references that cause execution of `main2` to dynamically load `libc.so`. [2]

**[1]** Compilers will differ on how standard library functions are defined; `gcc` has a file `printf.c` which defines `printf()` (and it's actually a pass-through to `vfprintf()`); other compilers might do it differently -- but the whole point of libraries is that you don't ever need to look at the *definition* of `printf()` and other library functions; you only need the *declaration* from the appropriate `.h` file in order to know how to *call* it in your own `.c` file.

**[2]** Or, if you build a *statically* linked executable, the code -- not just the symbol table -- is copied from the library file into the executable being built, and that executable can be run even on a machine without the `.so` files present.  Whether or not dynamic linking or static linking is better for building a given executable depends on several factors.

Comment: I think what the OP is missing regarding Q2 is that RAM residency is that paging operates on pages, not processes or libraries.

Comment: @landru27  sorry, I still don't get it. For Q1, why libvector.so and libc.so has relocation and symbol table information, isn't that everything needed by main2,c defined in libvector.so and libc.so(i.e printf is defined in libc.so), there is nothing in main2.c that define variable/function in libc.so?

Comment: @amjad : correct: there is nothing in main2.c to define functions found in libc;  I've edited my answer with an explanation

Comment: @amjad : another way to answer your follow-up question is to say : it is *because* `main2.c` does not have a definition of `printf()` that the linker needs to copy in the relocation and symbol table information for `printf()` from `libc.so`, so that when `main2` is executed, `libc.so` also gets loaded

Comment: @landru27 thanks for your answer. but I still don't get it.whenever the assembler encounters a reference to an object whose ultimate location is unknown, it generates a relocation entry that tells the linker how to
modify the reference when it merges the object file into an executable. For libc.so, everything is known(it has all definitions), so there shouldn't be any relocation entry for libc.so, isn't it?

Comment: @amjad : how is `main2.o` supposed to know *anything* about `libc.so`?  it doesn't -- until *after* the linker copies reference info from `libc.so` into `main2.o`

Comment: @landru27, sorry these is still something I'm missing, could you have a look at this question please? I make the question more straightforward https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53217849/relocation-entry-in-linking-c-programming

Comment: @landru27 Hi could you also look at this question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53292553/where-does-the-actual-code-of-exception-handler-reside-in-linux