# relocation entry in linking (C programming)

Tags: c, linker, dynamic-linking

still struggling to understand the relocation entry in Relocatable Object Files, let's say I have this simple C program:

```
//main1.c

void functionTest();

functionTest(){
   ...
}

int main()
{
   functionTest();
   return 0;
}
```

my questions are:

Q1. since everything is known to main1, so there is no relocation entry in .rel.text or .rel.data section of main1.o, is my understanding correct?

Q2. below is a picture illustrates how DLL works,

[image]

for libc.so, everything is known(it has all definitions just like main1), so why there is still relocation entries in libc.so? I can understand the symbol table information needs to be copied because they exist, how can you copy something that doesn't exist?

Q3. lets say below is the relocation entry structure;

```
typedef struct {
   int offset; /* Offset of the reference to relocate */
   int symbol:24, /* Symbol the reference should point to */
   type:8; /* Relocation type */
} Elf32_Rel;
```

so my understanding is there is already a relocation entry in main2.o for printf(), so the offset will be something like 8 or 9 bytes offset from caller function, symbol will be 'printf', type is R_386_PC32, so if there is another one needs to be copied from libc.so to main2.o, what's the structure of that relocation entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q1:**  Yes, if you compile the `main1.c` in your question, it will build *without* the need to link in anything, because it's not using functions that are defined elsewhere.

**Q2:**  That diagram won't apply to building `main1.c`, because `main1.c` does not use external functions.  But, in a program that *does* have a call to, say, `printf()`, here's what's going on: the diagram shows that relocation entries *about* `libc.so` are being placed *into* `main2.o`.  You ask "why there is still relocation entries in libc.so?" but the relocation entries are *not* being put *into* `libc.so`; they are being put into `main2.o`, and they *refer to* things in `libc.so`.

**Q2 follow-up #1:**  When you say "for libc.so, everything is known", that is true *only within* `libc.so`.  Anything that uses a function defined in `libc.so` will *not* know how that function is defined, ***until linking takes place***.  That's the function of `ld`: to copy reference info *from* a library like `libc.so` into a program *being built*, like `main2` in the diagram.  The reference info allows the kernel executing `main2` to *also load* `libc.so` into memory in such a way that execution can flow from the `main2` code over to the `libc.so` code and back to `main2` wherever `main2` calls a function whose definition / code resides in `libc.so`.

**Q3:**  I think the best way to put it is this:  The information that is used to *populate* the relocation structure within `main2.o` *comes from* `libc.so`.  Where I say that relocation entries are copied from `libc.so`, that's what I mean: information about the target (e.g. `printf()`) is taken from `libc.so` and used to provide values for the relocation entry in `main2.o` whose purpose is to tell the loader where to load the code for `printf()` from.

**Q3 follow-up #1:**  There is another sense in which `libc.so` has relocation entries: the thing that built `libc.so` added relocation entries to `libc.so`, so that anything that wants to use its (exportable) functions and variables can do so.  *These* don't need to be copied anywhere.  Part of building an object file is to create information for *internal* things that other programs might use; and, part of building a program is to populate the information about *external* things that it makes use of.  But the diagram looks to me like it's only meant to show that information *about* `libc.so` and `libvector.so` are added to `main2.o` so that the loader can load all the needed code into memory when `main2` is executed.

Comment: I can understand that there is a relocation entry in main2.o since it calls printf() which main2.c doesn't know the definition. But as my understanding is, when assembler translates main2.s to main2.o, a relocation entry(for printf) is created under main.o, so since main2.o already has the relocation entry, why it needs to copy another one from libc.so?

Comment: you mention "main.o" -- is that a typo?  I don't see any mention of main.o or main.c in the diagram nor in your question; please clarify and I will try to answer

Comment: yes, I mean main2.o, sorry for the typo, I have added a question 3 to the post which is my final question I think

Comment: @amjad  I've added an answer for your new Q3

Comment: Hi landru27, could you also have a look at this question, this will be my ultimate question in linking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53248960/multiple-weak-symbols-of-linker-puzzlesc-programming?noredirect=1#comment93382876_53248960

Comment: @amjad : I looked, but it's 404

Comment: so sorry I mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255357/consequences-of-multiple-weak-symbolsc-linker

Comment: @amjad  I apologize, but I am not familiar with weak symbols; they are not part of the C standard, and I have never used `#pragma weak`; I read briefly about why one might mark a symbol as weak, but frankly it sounds ill-advised, and seems generally to be considered non-portable;  I'm sure it's an interesting academic exercise, but I've not done anything along the lines of what your question is asking, and my only advice is to write code to test out empirically whether you or your instructor is correct about how they behave; HTH